# Adding parts to container when using [ImportingConstructor]

Tags: .net, mef

If I use `[ImportingConstructor]` on a part, how do I manually add it to the container? I can't add an instance because I would need to compose it myself. Should I also add a default constructor? Are catalogs the only way to get the part into the container?

```
class ClassA
{
  [ImportingConstructor]
  public ClassA(ClassB classB) { ... }

}

[Export]
class ClassB { ... }
```

WITHOUT using a catalog, how do you get an instance of ClassA into CompositionContainer?

Comment: Can you explain better what you're trying to do? With a code example maybe?

Comment: It's a basic question, instead of using [Import], you use [ImportingConstructor]. How do you add ClassA to a CompositionContainer without using a catgalog. All of the methods to do this require an instance, not a type so you have instantiate it yourself which defeats the purpose.

Comment: Is there a reason you're avoiding catalogs? What's wrong with using `TypeCatalog` here?

Comment: Good point, @Lester. Had my mind in another direction. Thats kind of what TypeCatalog is for. Makes more sense when you think about composition batch and the compose methods require instances which is where the problem comes in. Is there a way to do it without a catalog though.